# How to remove directory from url using mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i turn
    http://domain.com/foo/bar.jpg
into
    http://domain.com/bar
while keeping the rest of the website working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply be able to use...

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar.jpg$ /bar
```

Comment: All the images are user uploads. I have got it to work as http://domain.com/bar so far, but that means when i try go to http://domain.com/ it's attempting ot load http://domain.com/foo/index.php

Any idea of a better way to solve this?